# MacAir running macOS Monterey v12.5.1 crashes with error code 5

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I am encountering a recurring issue on my MacBook Air (M2 2022) running macOS Monterey version 12.5.1. Whenever I launch a specific window/application, it terminates unexpectedly, resulting in a crash. The error message I receive states: "The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'crashed', code: '5')".

I have attempted to troubleshoot this issue on my own, but unfortunately, I haven't found a solution. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem.

Here are some additional details:

MacBook Air: M2 2022
Operating System: macOS Monterey version 12.5.1
I have already tried the following steps without success:

Restarting my MacBook Air
Updating macOS Monterey to the latest version
Checking for any pending software updates for the specific window/application
Clearing caches and temporary files
If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has knowledge about error code 5 on macOS Monterey, your assistance would be highly appreciated. Please let me know if there is any additional information I can provide to help diagnose the problem.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Comment: Knowing what the app is might be a start. You should also approach the app's developer for guidance.

Comment: Updating to Monterey 12.6.7 fails? If so, how?

Comment: Is it VS Studio that's crashing or the app you're building?

Comment: @Allan it's VS Studio from what I see

Comment: This might help:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112202   Make sure you have the latest build.